# Why did Peter Jackson and Cate Blanchett take small uncredited roles in Hot Fuzz?

Tags: casting, cameo, hot-fuzz

So, it's no big secret, but [Peter Jackson and Cate Blanchett were both in Hot Fuzz.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425112/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)  Peter Jackson plays the guy who stabs Nick Angel in the hand and thus is in the movie for mere seconds.  Cate Blanchett plays Nick Angel's (soon to be) ex-girlfriend, is only in the movie for like a minute or so, and is hidden behind a mask so you wouldn't even know it was her.

These are two pretty big names to have such tiny, almost secretive, uncredited roles, so I imagine it was as a favor or something?  Is there any official word on why they took these parts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically, **they were both fans of *Shaun of the Dead* and knew the director**. From an [interview](http://movies.about.com/od/hotfuzz/a/hotfuzzew041307_2.htm) on About.com with Edgar Wright:

> Interviewer: **How did you get Cate Blanchett to do that one little cameo?**
>
> Wright: **I'd met her in LA and knew that she was a fan of Shaun of the Dead**, so that was kind of a start. The first thing we wrote in Hot Fuzz is the kind of the girlfriend scene with the CSI sort of [setup]. The first joke was basically that you have an emotive scene with him saying farewell to his girlfriend and being very sentimental and you can't see her face. [...] **In a weird way this whole Cate Blanchett thing was sort of a slight kind of joke on that. ‘Let's get an Oscar winner in there but not see her face.’ And she was totally up for that joke.** She loved it. And for the record - and this is why Cate Blanchett goes to heaven - she gave her fee to charity. She is one nice lady.”
>
> Interviewer: You also had a second person in there that might not be recognized by audiences.
>
> Wright: Oh, yeah, **Peter Jackson is in there as well.** The irony of Peter Jackson is that we got him to play Santa Claus and the irony is that we had to give him a fake beard and pad him up. The two things that three years ago would be the prerequisite for the role, like he'd both lost.
>
> **He was in the UK and he was a big supporter for Shaun of the Dead since it came out. I'd become friends with him,** which was great. I actually went over on a little holiday when they were shooting Kong, which was great, and hung around on the set like a work experience kid. I was telling him about Hot Fuzz and **he said, ‘I'll be in the UK and I'll do a cameo if you want.’ Then I thought, ‘F#@k, he should play Santa.’** It was brilliant, actually. It was really cool because it was so sweet. He was in London for a week and we actually shooting outside and he came all the way down. His cameo is like five seconds long. He was really cool.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize Wright knew so many bigwigs!  Awesome!